# Python/Tkinter ¿Cómo cargar una imagen dentro de canvas que aparezca redimensionada?

Tags: python, tkinter

Si el canvas tiene un tamaño fijo, ¿cómo hacer para que una imagen aparezca redimensionada dentro del canvas sin perder su relación de tamaño y sin alterar el tamaño de la imagen original?
Por ejemplo, si el canvas mide 400x400 px de tamaño pero quiero cargar una imagen de 600x300 px de tamaño sin que cambie el tamaño del canvas pero que se pueda ver la imagen completa redimensionada hacerle retoques o añadirle una leyenda y luego grabarla con ImageGrab y que siga teniendo sus dimensiones originales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planteas varias preguntas en realidad. Para ajustar la imagen al canvas **sin cambiar su relación de aspecto** puedes usar el método `Image.resize()` de `PIL` (usar `Pillow` para `Python 3.x`).

Para ello calculamos el factor de reescalado para el ancho y el alto como:

```
factor_reescalado_ancho = nuevo_ancho / ancho_imagen_original
factor_reescalado_alto = nuevo_alto / alto_imagen_original
```

Como no queremos que la imagen cambie su relación de aspecto debemos usar el menor de ellos para calcular tanto el alto como el ancho de la nueva imagen.

El siguiente código toma una imágen y la reescala para mostrarla dentro de un `Canvas` de 400 x 400 sin cambiar su relación de aspecto.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = tk.Tk()

pic = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

img = Image.open(pic)

o_size = img.size   #Tamaño original de la imagen
f_size = (400, 400) #Tamaño del canvas donde se mostrará la imagen


factor = min(float(f_size[1])/o_size[1], float(f_size[0])/o_size[0])
width = int(o_size[0] * factor)
height = int(o_size[1] * factor)

rImg= img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
rImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rImg)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=f_size[0], height= f_size[1])
canvas.create_image(f_size[0]/2, f_size[1]/2, anchor=tk.CENTER, image=rImg, tags="img")
canvas.pack(fill=None, expand=False)

root.mainloop()
```

La segunda cuestión que planteas es que los cambios y ediciones que apliques en este lienzo se puedan guardar pero aplicados a la imagen original. Si guardas  la imagen de tu lienzo obtendras una imagen de `400 x alto`, `ancho x 400` o de `400 x 400` dependiendo de como sea la imagen original.

Puedes plantear varias estrategias para solucionar esto. Por ejmplo, puedes crear otro `Canvas` oculto (no lo llegas a mostrar en la ventana principal), cargas en el la imagen original y aplicas los mismos cambios que hagas en el `Canvas` de 400 x 400 aplicando las correciones oportunas sobre coordenadas, tamaño de fuente, grosor de lineas, tamaño de los objetos, etc para que los cambios sean proporcionales. Luego guardas la imagen del `Canvas` oculto.

Comment: Válgame! Más cara la bala que la pistola! Muchas gracias, por la información. Espero pueda servir y posteo el resultado.

Comment: @Toño la verdad es que es muy interesante tu pregunta, no tanto lo de redimencionar la imagen sino lo de editarla en la redimencionada y guardarla en su tamaño original con los cambios. Aunque hay biblitecas gráficas como pyQt que hacen esto más sencillo, siempre existe la forma,. Con Tkinter a pesar de ser más básico he visto autenticas obras de arte, eso si toca calentarse la cabeza... pero luego sienta tan bien conseguirlo... No se si existirá alguna forma más simple que la que propongo, seguiré indagando cuando pueda a ver. El tema me parece interesante como digo.